# Exception in Visual Studio 2022 17.3.2 out as June 15, 2022

Tags: exception

I just installed the last update to Visual Studio 2022 17.3.2 this day.
. Load my .Maui application (on mobile Android)
. Clean the Solution
. Close the solution and close Visual Studio
. Delete /bin and /obj folders of the application
Then I launch VS and load the solution
The solution compiles without any error.
Problem :
I run and after deployment I see the splash screen(Blue .NET flash screen)
After the splash screen I receive the following :

> Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ToPlatformException: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Items.CollectionViewHandler
> found for >Microsoft.Maui.Controls.CollectionView is incompatible'

Has anyone already seen this ?

Comment: This exception disappears if I comment out the CollectionView.EmptyView

Comment: Yes, I just got the same error on my CollectionView page.  Commenting out the EmptyView property avoids the error.